# How to flip without using mirror modifier

Tags: mirror

I have a model with a yellow red and green color mention just to understand. A Green color base on that a yellow and a red color object are placed. Red color object is to under where i have to place the object. I want the yellow color object to be flip to other side where the red cylinder is located. The problem is the yellow object is made of 4-5 mesh and i do not want to join and make the mirror. I just want to flip that complete yellow model to red cylinder position without joining the parts and without mirror modifier. The reason why i do not want to join is later i have to animate the seperate parts. So is there any quick way to flip or addon so that my complete model can flip.blender file here ......[image] [image]

Comment: from the image it seems the yellow part has Y symmetry, so you could simply put the cursor at the base mesh center, then set pivot point at cursor, then select the yellow part (or a duplicate if it needs to be doubled on the other side), and rotate it with R Z 180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the green object, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and click *cursor to selected*.

[image]

Change the pivot point to *3D Cursor*.

[image]

Deselect the green object, select the yellow objects, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the objects and afterwards press <kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd>,<kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>8</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd>.

[image]

Note that the screencaster in the gif above did not display the <kbd>Z</kbd>,<kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>8</kbd> and <kbd>0</kbd> keys being pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Select green object, press Shift+S and choose cursor to selected. Change pivot center for rotation/scaling to 3D cursor.Select yellow object (all meshes) and either press S,X -1 (to scale it by value of -1 on the X axis, which will cause to mirror the object to the other side) or CTRL+M,X (which will cause to mirror object to the other side)
[image]

Comment: thanks for reply the flipping work but as in mirror other mesh is created with with flip. As i have to some work i have delete the red cylinder and then duplicate the yellow and then ctrl+m,x and then align. Is there any way it directly flip to the position where the red cylinder is present with the duplicate copy.

Comment: This flip doesn't create other mesh.If you have another mesh, then you must've duplicated it. If you would do exactly, as I wrote, you would have all yellow object parts exactly on the oposite side of the green base.If you have another outcome, then you're doing something not exactly like I told you or you don't understand something as you should, so I'll add .gif to the answer.